# Google recaptcha V2 what are best practices for reset

Tags: security, recaptcha

we just changed our old capctha (bot-detect) to googols recaptcha.
until now, when ever an error on the server side occurred (business level error)
when returned the response we rested the capctha. 
for example:
login form-> wrong password.
now, i noticed the new recapctha has a automatic experation. it seems that on the same form in this same page session there is no need to re check the user. 
on the other hand there seems to be a reset function:

> grecaptcha.reset();

what is the pest practice here? should i always ask for a new capctha test? or trust goggles initial test?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you and your use case , depending on requirement if you think that the if there is significantly less time between multiple user data submission on the same form in the same session , go for a new captcha test.